Create gc bucket with bash script
I want to automate the process of creating a Google Cloud bucket. For this, I have written a script that should do it. It should make a bucket to store media in from a dotnet appliation. Without the bucket, the script works and deploys. Only if I put the bucket section in the script, it won't work anymore.
The deploy script:
create_bucket() {
    gcloud storage buckets create $BUCKET_NAME \
        --project "$PROJECT_ID" \
        --location "$ZONE" \
        --versioning \
        --logging \
        --transfer-protocol=HTTPS \
        --service-account=$SERVICE_ACCOUNT

    # Update environment variable file
    set_env_var "ASPNETCORE_STORAGE_BUCKET" "$BUCKET_NAME"
}

The config file:
BUCKET_NAME="phygital-bucket"

However, I always get an error that there is a problem with the parameters. It's strange because a colleague of mine can run this script without any problems.
the error:
ERROR: (gcloud.storage.buckets.create) unrecognized arguments:
  --versioning (did you mean '--verbosity'?)
  --logging (did you mean '--location'?)
  --transfer-protocol=HTTPS
  --service-account=phygital-service-account@phygital-222256.iam.gserviceaccount.com (did you mean '--impersonate-service-account'

I tried many other things but nothing really helped. The deploy file is pretty big, because it deploys an entire dotnet application. So The way I set up the service account should be correct.
I appreciate your help!!

Did you update your gcloud CLI? Do you have the same version as your colleague?

I have no idea what version he is using, but I just updated mine to the newest and still doesn't works

The flags you are using when you call the gcloud command are not allowed. To see a list of allowed flags, you can reference the documentation for the gcloud storage buckets create command.

And how would you set your service-account?
